# How to work with numbers that have to be split into seperate parts?

Tags: javascript

So I am currently in prep-course and a lot of the possible leetcode problems we are going to have during the exam are to do with things like factorials and numbers.

For instance this is one of the problems

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
> For example:
>
> ```
>  persistence(39) === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
>                        // and 4 has only one digit
>
>  persistence(999) === 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
>                         // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2
>
>  persistence(4) === 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
> ```

Now my question is I know that we can use something like this

```
var arr = num.toString().split('');
```

And this will give us the arr of strings, and we can simply call something like this in the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  var currentNum = Number(arr[i]);
}
```

But I am struggling to figure out how I would implement maybe a while loop or some conditional to continue the loop through the problem.

For instance in this case 39 would become

```
39-> 3*9 | (27) 27-> 2*7 | (14) 14-> 1*4
```

However im struggling to work through how to actually do the continuous loop. Like if it where just to do one loop I can do that, but the recursion is where I am lost.

If anyone could walk me through this with some level of detail it would be really helpfull, thanks!

Comment: Is recursion being discussed by your instructor? It can be done without recursion, im just asking.

Comment: Can you do it with one loop, or not? I did not understand that.

Comment: @GetSet currently its self study for a technical assessment to get in so there are no instructors available. (its a bootcamp in SF) and they want use to use whatever where comfortable with using. So we can use recursion, or non recursion, but Ideally I would like to learn the simpler way of doing it if there is a way to do it without recursion.

Comment: I'll post an answer i just tried, and will add some comments to it walk you thru.

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos Im not sure I understand your question, but as far as my knoweldge goes I can't figure out a way to do it with only one loop although I'm sure there is, or as  GetSet pointed out, there is also a way to be done without recursion it seems.

Comment: @GetSet Thanks I really appreciate it!~

Comment: i gave u 11 lines of straightforward code.... look for the answer using persistence(num)

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to be on the right track with the while loop so thats what I used. I'll add more comments to this code on "edits" after I post.

```js
function p(n) {

    // n = n.toString();
    // v = n;

    var cnt = 0;

    var v = n.toString();
    
    while (v.length > 1) {
        var digits = v.split('');
        
        var product = 1;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            product *= parseInt( digits[i] );
        }
        
        v = product.toString();

        cnt++;
        
    }
    
    // This line returns the final value, not the "count" or "persistence"
    // return parseInt(v);

    // This line (edit) returns the "persistence"
    return cnt;
    
}

console.log( p(999) );
console.log( p(39) );
console.log( p(4) );
```

Basically what's at work here is `n` is converted to a string in case it arrived as a number. Next the `while` loop continues so long as `v` length is more than one, so really you could just set `v = n.toString()` there, same difference.

Now if v's length is more than 1 than likewise, v is not less than 10. So the loop continues until that happens with the rest of the logic inside the loop.

`v` is a string so it's split into digits as you suggested in your question.

`product` starts out as `1` as opposed to `0` because of obvious reasons. The digits are multiplied together via the for loop.

Then that product becomes the new `v` so that the loop can either iterate again, or terminate based on the `while` condition.

Comment: Okay wow this is really helpful actually, especially with using while loops, I really appreciate the help on this one! :)

Comment: No prob. I prefer non-recursion personally as well. For me its easier on the eyes and brain.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested in a recursive version:

```js
function p(input){
const v = input.toString();
if(v.length<=1){
   return 0;
}

let product = 1;
for(var i=0;i< v.length;i++)
{
   product *= parseInt(v[i]);
}

   return p(product)+1;
}

console.log(p(999));
console.log(p(39));
console.log(p(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution. Hope it helps!

```js
function p(num){
  var new_num = 1,
      sNumber = num.toString(),
      len = sNumber.length,
      counter = 0;

  while(len > 1) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
      new_num = new_num * parseInt(sNumber.charAt(i));
    }
    sNumber = new_num.toString();
    len = sNumber.length;
    new_num=1;
  }
  return counter;
 }
console.log(p(39));
console.log(p(999));
console.log(p(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that will perform multiplication and then call it each time the number is bigger than 10

```js
function getper(n){
  var arr = n.toString().split('');
  i=1
  res= multi(arr)
  do{
   if(res>10) {
    na= res.toString().split('')
    res=multi(na)
    if(res<10){
       i=-1
    }
    else i++
   }
      else i=-1

  }while(i>0)
  return res
}
console.log(getper(39))
console.log(getper(999));
console.log(getper(4));
function multi(arr){
 return arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
    return acc*curr
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting some things might look fancy to you, but as a fellow javascript user, u gotta learn to do straightfoward solutions

```js
function persistence(num){
  var numArr = num.toString().split``; //only these quotes skip out the brackets for functions. eg: functionName('abc'+varName) is the same as functionName`abc${varName}`
  var ans = 0;
  while(numArr.length > 1){
    var newNum = 1;
    numArr.forEach((a,i)=>{newNum *= a}); //this is basically a for loop structure for arraays. a is the element, i is the index. "1" is the same as 1 when it comes to multiplication, division and subtraction (NOT ADDITION)
    numArr = newNum.toString().split``;
    ans++;
  }
  return(ans);
}
//solution examples
console.log(persistence(999));
console.log(persistence(81));
console.log(persistence(4));
console.log(persistence(39));
//yes, it looks simple and straightfoward... ur welcome
```